# Unable to find an object's place inside a vector

Tags: c++, class, iterator

```
int RobotDB::findRobot(const std::string name) {
  int index = 0;
  RobotVec_it iter_find;
  iter_find = robots.begin();
  while (iter_find != robots.end()) {
    if (( * iter_find) - > getName() == name) {
      return index;
    }
    index++;
    iter_find++;
  }
  return -1;
}

class Robot {
  private:
    Coordinate coordinate;
    const string name;
    int dust_bin;
    connection_e con;
};

inline const string & getName() {
  return name;
}
```

I have a vector of *Robot, Robot is a class I was given, containing a coordinate, name, dust bin that contains the amount of dust collected and if the robot status is COMMUNICABLE or NON-COMMUNICABLE which affects the ability to send him orders.
I write the function findRobot to help me identify a specific robot inside the robots vector. However, using the debug I saw that something isn't working right. Maybe the function getName() doesn't really returns the name like it should. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

I added the relevant codes, findRobot appears in RobotDB.cpp while the class and the getName function are located in RobotDB.h

Comment: Looks correct. Are you there aren't other things you're missing?

Comment: "something isn't working right". Care to elaborate ?

Comment: Either you didn't copy/paste your code correctly or `getName()` isn't a method of `class Robot`. (It definitely is not in the sample code you presented.) IMHO, as is, you cannot even compile it.

Comment: @Incomputable _"Looks correct."_ I do not agree.

Comment: @Scheff, well, I ignored everything below the find function, since he mentioned debugger, which implies some running of the code. And yes, the getter should be part if the class. Constructor wouldn't hurt, lol.

Comment: @Incomputable I agree that I cannot find anything suspicuous in `RobotDB::findRobot()` although it really is not elegant and the formatting is terrible... (but that's a matter of taste not a technical issue.)

Comment: @Scheff, I proposed edit with formatting. Waiting in the queue. And yes, `std::find` would be  better.

Comment: @hivert Using the debugger I noticed that while it should get the name from getName() it doesn't do that for some reason, the if statements gets false and goes to return -1. Not sure if I know how to describe it better than that.  I made a constructor I just didn't think it has anything to do with the problem. As for the way the code is written I only code for a few months so I guess I will learn how to code better with time. getName() is a class method in the public section of Robot I just didn't copy all the code. Thanks for your comments

Comment: @B.Nadler This sounds somehow suspicious. From my experience with the (IMHO really good) VS internal debugger, sometimes the cursor (or arrow) is displayed just behind the "current point". Thus, I think it's possible that the `if` statement is even not reached. Did you check that your `robots` container is not empty?

Comment: @B.Nadler To check, whether I was on the right trace, set a break point at the line of the `if` statement to be sure that it is reached. If the debugger stops their, then the `robots` vector cannot be empty (because the former `while` condition check returned true).